# WSO2 API Manager, 1.6.0: axis2.xml typo mistake?

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wso2-esb

Form the default installattion I think I see a typo mistake in axis2.xml, from line 300:

```
   <transportReceiver name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener">
        <parameter name="port" locked="false">8243</parameter>
        <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>-->
        <!--parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">hostname or IP address</parameter-->
        <!--parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">https://apachehost:port/somepath</parameter-->
        <parameter name="httpGetProcessor" locked="false">org.wso2.carbon.transport.nhttp.api.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor</parameter>
        <parameter name="keystore" locked="false">
```

I think at the end of the third line the "-->" is wrong. It should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It must be a mistake.

Please [create a JIRA for API Manager](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER) project.

You may also use [WSO2 dev@ mailing list](http://wso2.com/mail/) to communicate these type of issues and create JIRAs.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Great! Thanks for creating the JIRA!